# 'UNRECOGNIZED NAME RESULT IN QUERY'

Tags: google-bigquery

Why it keeps prompting as "Unrecognized name" in the result when I run the query on Google BigQuery even I copied it right and did sourced the right table.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please share a screenshot if possible, or at the very least give us an example of the code you're running and some example data so we can help.